# Django 2.2 upgrade - mongoengine query performance

Tags: django

We are trying to upgrade from Django 2.1.11 to 2.2.4. During the upgrade we noticed a significant performance drop relating to queries made through the mongoengine library (http://mongoengine.org/)

We did some profiling with pyspy (https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) and noticed the control flow is significantly different and there are lots of extra function calls relating to pagination.

I can't find anything in the release notes for Django 2.2 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/) that suggests why we might be getting the problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

We have tried doing some profiling with pyspy and some other tools and we tried different minor versions but it seems to broken in all Django 2.2 versions.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(BaseOverview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx['result_template_name'] = self.result_template_name
    ctx['action_form'] = self.action_form
    ctx['page_size_form'] = self.page_size_form
    ctx['submitted'] = self.submitted
    ctx['model'] = self.model
    ctx['paginate'] = self.paginate_by

    results = ctx[self.context_object_name]

    if not isinstance(results, list):
        # Need to evaluate the queryset, so attached data remains set
        results = results.select_related(max_depth=self.select_depth)
        self.attach(results, self.request.session['environment'])

        # assert len(results) <= self.paginate_by
        ctx[self.context_object_name] = results

    return ctx
```

Where results is a mongoengine Document class instance
[pyspy output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2tbU.png)

Comment: Is this your code (`get_context_data`)? Or this generic django code? And why does your left benchmark show 102 results and your right one 20500? Is this a view of django admin maybe where in the first benchmark you had less than 100 result to display hence no pagination and in the right one > 100 results hence the pagination?

Comment: Yeh this is my code from a class which overrides djangos ListView. I don't know why those samples are different, I guess thats what I am trying to find out, i.e why it is making all of these extra function calls.

Comment: I'm saying it looks like you're not querying the same database contents. You are saying you are? Both tests are run with the exact same code against the same database contents? And can you create a standard ListView (no customisation) and check the same there?

Comment: Yeh it appears like behaviour with the database is different and the IO with the Mongo DB is why it is taking so long. But it is the exact same code just a different Django version.